# Bootstrap jQuery show specific tab on pageload

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show a specific tab, after a form has been submitted.
The page does some calculations, when a form is submitted, and I would like to show the results in a specific tab.

This is the code I have now:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tab_info').tab('show')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul id="formtabs" class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_form">Form</a></li>
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_resultat">Resultat</a></li>
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_formel">Formel</a></li>
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_info">Informationer</a></li>
 </ul>
  
 <div class="tab-content">
   <div id="tab_form" class="tab-pane active">
     <div class="panel-body">Form</div>
   </div>
   <div id="tab_resultat" class="tab-pane">
     <div class="panel-body">Resultat</div>
   </div>
   
      <div id="tab_formel" class="tab-pane">
     <div class="panel-body">Formel</div>
   </div>
     
      <div id="tab_info" class="tab-pane">
     <div class="panel-body">Information</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Is the form submitted via AJAX? If not then you would be best to show the tab via the response from the server instead of using JS on the client

Comment: do an if else condition based on the result you get, if a, then  $('#tab_info').tab('show') else  $('tab_resultat').tab('show')?

Comment: ye, i will use PHP to show the script when needed. The problem is that the current code does not show the tab, when the page is loading. It stay on the active one..... update: ahhh, your right (Rory). I can just add the class "active" to the tab in my code, to show the tab I want after form has been submitted. No js needed. It would be nice to know, why the code does not work though. Shouldnt it display the tab_info tab after the page is loaded?

Comment: Which tab do you want to show after submit?

Comment: tab_info (on pageload)

Comment: If you are using bootstrap place a hidden class in your div to hide, you can toggle class "hidden" using `$('#tab-info').removeClass('hidden')`. Place this in a function that loads on your form submit. `$('#submitBtnID').click('keydown, keyup', function() {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/nart6rat/

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#tab_info"]').tab('show')
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="formtabs" class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_form">Form</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_resultat">Resultat</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_formel">Formel</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_info">Informationer</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab_form" class="tab-pane active">
    <div class="panel-body">Form</div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab_resultat" class="tab-pane">
    <div class="panel-body">Resultat</div>
  </div>

  <div id="tab_formel" class="tab-pane">
    <div class="panel-body">Formel</div>
  </div>

  <div id="tab_info" class="tab-pane">
    <div class="panel-body">Information</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here in the example, I'm moving to "**Informationer**" tab on **page load** whereas in your case once you **submit** **the form** you move to the tab using the following **JavaScript code**

```
$('.nav-tabs a[href="#tab_info"]').tab('show')
```